# DataTables, calculated column

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to create a column in my table using the DataTable plugin, that is calculated using values from two previous columns.

Something like this.. *(Price)(QTY)=Total*

```
|| Price || QTY || Total||
==========================
||  5    ||  2  ||  10  ||
||  10   ||  3  ||  30  ||
||  4    ||  1  ||  4   ||
```

I feel like it should be simple, but I can't get it to work. [Here is a similar question I tried to follow.](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25675/how-to-display-computed-column-dynamically-using-jquery-datatables)

### Here is my JS file where I am initializing the table

```
var table = $('#tempPOs').DataTable( {
        dom: 'frtip', //Bfrtip (removed the B to get rid of the buttons)
        ajax: '/inventory/DTResources/php/table.tempPOs.php',
        columns: [
        { "data": "pmkPart" },
        { "data": "PartNumber" },
        { "data": "Description" },
        { "data": "fnkManufacturer" },
        { "data": "Notes" },
        { "data": "EachPrice", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) },
        { "data": "Quantity" },
        { "data": "Username" },
        {
            data: null,
            className: "center",
            defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_remove">Remove</a>'
        }
        ],
        select: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [
        { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
        { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
        { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
        ],

    } );
```

### Here is my HTML

```
<th>Part ID</th>
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Part Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Total Price</th>
<th>Remove</th>
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `render` option similar to how you used it for the `"EachPrice"` field. There is a built-in function documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) if you want to get more information, but I'll outline what it would look like for you below.

```
columns: [
    /*other columns omitted for example*/
    { 
        "data": null, //data is null since we want to access ALL data
                      //for the sake of our calculation below
        "render": function(data,type,row) { return (data["price"] * data["quantity"])}
    }

],
```

In this way you can use other columns from `data` to render output for this column.

This option can be used to display basically anything you want, as long as it can be calculated with a function. If you want to get more information on the usage of the `render` option, take a look at the link above.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I knew it had to be something simple, I just couldn't get the syntax correct.

Comment: @Chris H.,  is it possible to sort this column?

Comment: what if data has inner object, 
example
data["item.price"] will not work