# dynamically add a column to Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm have a js datatable with json content in front of me

```
$('#data').DataTable( {
     data: data,
     columns : [ 
         { data: "number" },
         { data: "firstname" }, 
         { data: "lastname" }
    ]
});
```

the datatable itself fills itself as intended. However, I'd like to add another column at the end of the table which is not quite part of the data I get. Let's say I want to add a button or a link there.

is there a quick way to add another column and use the data (eg. number)?

Desired resault for the table:

```
Number | Firstname | Lastname | Action
001    | John      | Doe      | link to ...page?nr=001
023    | Jane      | Doe      | link to ...page?nr=023
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111245/datatables-calculated-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code might do your work,

```
$('#data').DataTable( {
     data: data,
     columns : [ 
         { data: "number" },
         { data: "firstname" }, 
         { data: "lastname" },
         {
             "data": null,
             "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
               return '<a href="'+data['number']+'">View Detail</a>'; }
         },
    ]
});
```

Comment: what can we do if we have to check for permissions for actions. If yes then show the column. I tried by checking permissions in render function which is returning empty column in case of null returned or empty returned. Only way for me is to check permission before defining the column i.e. before {}. Is it the only approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on example found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

```js
function Person( firstname, lastname, age ) {
    this._firstname = firstname;
    this._lastname  = lastname;
    this._age       = age;
 
    this.firstname = function () {
        return this._firstname;
    };

    this.lastname = function () {
        return this._lastname;
    };
    
    this.age = function () {
        return this._age;
    };
    
    this.link = function () {
        return '<a href="linkto...'+this._age+'">linkto...'+this._age+'</a>';
    };
 
}
 
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: null, render: 'firstname' },
            { data: null, render: 'lastname' },
            { data: null, render: 'age'  },
            { data: null, render: 'link' }
        ]
    });
 
    table.row.add( new Person( 'Airi', 'Satou', 33 ) );
    table.row.add( new Person( 'Angelica', 'Ramos', 47 ) );
    table.row.add( new Person( 'Ashton', 'Cox', 66 ) );
    table.draw();
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
</table>
```